# GWT vs Spring: applicationContext is null if I change the page

Tags: java, javascript, spring, gwt, gwt-rpc

I am inheriting a project from a developer who left, and I am trying to understand GWT and Spring Framework.

The original problem that lead me to this path: GWT had one module where I loaded ALL third party javascripts... that could result in conflicts. Example, I would include chart drawing libraries, etc. all in one page.
Possible solutions: Have the chart drawing library in an iframe so that it would not conflict with other third party libraries of javascript... OR open the page in a new window.

I decided to go with a new window.

So I did this:

```
Window.Location.assign(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()
            + "chartModule.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997/");
```

However, in my new chartModule.java (GWT) the problem I have is I do not have the beans/classses defined in (Spring framework) applicationContext.xml anymore:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

And applicationContext is null after I have changed the host page url... so I do not have any beans that I tried autowiring...

Is it possible to reload the beans from applicationContext.xml??

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--  This file has properties that are used by other XML files loaded via ${var name} syntax -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/environment.properties" />

    <import resource="spring-security-cas.xml" />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
        as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
        correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javamango.sixtydegrees" />
    <import resource="mongo-config.xml" />
    <import resource="rabbitmq-context.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-mail.xml" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use spring beans on client side. If you want retriewe some data from spring in gwt, you can do this at two ways:

1) use server side library like [gwt-sl](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-sl/) to inject spring beans in gwt servlet

```
@Service("greetingService")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    UserFileService userFileService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
}
```

now you can autowire spring beans and obtain data via gwt-rpc

2) put data via jsp in hidden html form fields and retriewe data from it

```
<input type="hidden" value="7" id="documentid"/>

String id = (InputElement) (Element) DOM.getElementById("documentid").value
```